# DateTime issue in magento

Tags: magento, datetime

There is an issue in my magento site in displaying date. In Database table, Date is stored with value '2013-06-12 14:14:57' and when date is displaying in admin section it becomes 'Jun 12, 2013 10:14:57 PM', it is increasing 8 hours by the original value stored in database.

Below is the code which i am using

```
$this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
        ));
```

Can anyone tell me why this happen?

Comment: It stores the correct time in DB right Mr. Vaibhav ?

Comment: What's your offset from UTC. Magento stores records in UTC and displays in local usually.

Comment: Yes  Chiragit007. Correct time is inserted in DB.

Comment: Singapore Standard Time (Asia/Singapore) timezone set in admin configuration